# Boto3 create_image for AMI creation - save ALL volumes

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

My aim is to create an AMI image of ec2 instance.
will the below code store all the block volumes with deletion on termination enabled ?

[PFA image with my requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CYmf.png)

```
def create _Image(instance_id):

    name = f"{instance_id}_Image_Backup_{date}"
    try:
        response = ec2_con.create_image(
            InstanceId=instance_id,
            NoReboot=True,
            Name=name,
            Description=f'AMI created on {date} for patching activity')

        ami_image_id = response['ImageId']
        waiter = ec2_con.get_waiter('image_available')
        waiter.wait(
            ImageIds=[ami_image_id])

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        sys.exit(1)

    else:
        print(f"Image {ami_image_id} is created successfully and available")
        return ami_image_id
```

Answer (score 0):

The AMI created will keep the data for EBS-based volumes, even if the underlying volumes get deleted. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-an-ami-ebs.html):

> During the AMI-creation process, Amazon EC2 creates **snapshots** of your instance's root volume and **any other EBS volumes attached** to your instance.